# bootstrap reuse html tags code in different pages

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using angularJS with bootstrap.

I have following html code in ResetAndRegisterCommon.html

```
<div class="error"
     ng-show="resetRegisterForm.Email.$invalid&& resetRegisterForm.Email.$dirty">
    <span ng-show="resetRegisterForm.Email.$error">

        <div class="alert alert-warning">
            Warning! Please enter valid email address
        </div>
    </span>
</div>
```

I would like to reuse the above code in Mypage1.html and Mypage2.html

I have tried the following code in Mypage1.html and Mypage2.html but the html tag does not render at all in Mypage1.html and Mypage2.html.

```
<link rel="import" href="ResetAndRegisterCommon.html">
```

Comment: You have to use JS to access the content of the imported file.

Answer (score 0):

You need JS to access the contents of the imported file. It's actually really easy though.

Let's give your `<link>` an id so we can call it.

```
<link rel="import" href="page.html" id="import">
```

Now we use JS to call it

```
var doc = document.querySelector('#import').import;
```

Now we grab the DOM from the document that was imported

```
var error = doc.querySelector('.error');
```

Then we clone it and append it to the current page

```
document.body.appendChild(error.CloneNode(true));
```

Comment: How can I do that in AngularJS?

Comment: I'm not familiar with angular, but this is pure JS so it should work in your application.